# Rotation-safe Latin squares

Tags: code-golf, grid, permutations

**A Latin square is a square that has no repeated symbols in either the X or Y columns**.  For example:

```
ABCD    
DABC
CDAB
BCDA
```

is one such square.  Notice how every column and row contains a permutation of the same 4 letters.

However, our Latin square has a problem:  **If I were to rotate the second row (`DABC`) 1 to the left, I'd end up with `ABCD`, which is identical to the permutation above it.**  If it is *impossible* to rotate any 1 column/row and obtain another column/row, then we consider the square to be **rotation safe**.

For example:

```
ABCD
BDAC
CADB
DCBA
```

is rotation safe.  The grid has the following properties:

1. **Point [0,N] uses the Nth symbol**
2. **Point [0,N] and [N,0] are always the same symbol**.  (I'd like to also say that [x,y] and [y,x] are also always the same letter, but I can't prove it)

**Your task is to print out 1 rotation-safe Latin square, when passed N.**  I don't care if you output letters, numbers, a list, or a 2D array.  **If you use numbers, the top column and row must be `0,1,2,3,...` (in that order).  If you use letters, then it must be `A,B,C,D,....`**

For example, if your input was 4, you should either print:

```
0,1,2,3            0,1,2,3
1,3,0,2     or     1,0,3,2
2,0,3,1            2,3,1,0
3,2,1,0            3,2,0,1
```

There are no rotation-safe Latin squares of size less than 4.  I don't care what your program does if N is less than 4.  For the curious, the number of rotation-safe squares is (starting at 4):  `2,5,5906,(too long to calculate)`

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so try to make answers as short as possible in your favorite language!

Comment: Is there a time limit? (Related: Are Monte Carlo methods allowed if they are technically not guaranteed to terminate for high values of `N` due to insufficient random number quality?)

Comment: No time limit, but your solution should be guaranteed to terminate.

Comment: For 1-indexed languages, can the first row be `1,2,3,...`?

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778048/counting-the-number-of-latin-squares),[related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8sdlX3gLxY)

Comment: @miles yes, that is fine

Comment: that is easily done with some built in functions in matlab but they spend eras to finish, are they allowed ?

Comment: @Agawa001 if the built-in specifically calculates rotation-safe Latin squares, then it isn't allowed. Otherwise, you are OK.

Comment: @Maltysen just one.

Comment: @Agawa001 I'm curious what those builtins are...

Comment: @LuisMendo , nathan builtins for unique row permutations combined in a sort they generate unique matrix column permutations, but they take forever.

Comment: @Sp3000 That sequence is different:  It counts rotation-safe latin squares, but it doesn't count them multiple times.  I won't claim that I didn't make a mistake, but I'm not sure if that sequence is sufficient evidence.

Comment: Is there a maximum number that N can be? That is, what's the largest N that the code has to be able to handle?

Comment: @GlenO Whatever integer size your language supports.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 29 bytes

Brute force.

```
hf&!@JsCBTsm.>RdJStQ.A{IMJ^.p
```

Does not finish online even for `n=4`, but you can try it out locally, or [run this modified version online for one more byte](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hf%26.A%7BIMCT%21%40JsCBTsm.%3ERdJStQ%5E.p&input=4&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## Sqlserver 2012 - 918 bytes

On my box this runs for @k = 5, although it takes 16 seconds.

This is code building code(watch out Skynet, you have competition)

Is there a price for the longest script?

```
DECLARE @k int = 4;

DECLARE @t VARCHAR(max)='WITH C as(SELECT
top '+left(@k,1)+'row_number()over(order by 1/0)n
FROM sys.messages),D(nÆ)as(SELECT
concat(~),~
FROM Ø
WHERE |)SELECT top 1~ FROM Å
WHERE 1=1',@
varchar(999)=''SELECT @+=','+CHAR(x+65)FROM(values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))x(x)WHERE x<@k
SELECT
@t=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@t,'Æ',@),'Ø',STUFF(REPLACE(@,',',',C '),1,1,'')),'Å',STUFF(REPLACE(@,',',',D
'),1,1,'')),'~',STUFF(REPLACE(@,',','.n,'),1,3,'')+'.n'),@='';WITH C as(SELECT top(@k)x
FROM(values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))x(x))SELECT @+=' AND
'+char(65+C.x)+'.n<>'+char(65+D.x)+'.n'FROM c,c d WHERE C.x<D.x
SELECT @t=REPLACE(@t,'|',STUFF(@,1,4,''));WITH A
as(SELECT top(@k)x
FROM(values(65),(66),(67),(68),(69),(70))x(x))SELECT @t+='AND
'+char(A.x)+'.'+char(C.x)+'<>'+CHAR(B.x)+'.'+char(C.x)+' AND
'+char(A.x)+'.n+'+char(A.x)+'.n'+'
not like''%''+'+char(B.x)+'.n+''%'''FROM A,A B,A C
WHERE A.x<>B.x and C.x<>B.x
EXEC(@t)
```

[Try online!](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/485215/rotation-safe-latin-squares)