# How many Latin Squares?

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

A Latin Square is a square of size **n × n** containing numbers **1** to **n** inclusive. Each number occurs once in each row and column.

An example of a 3 × 3 Latin Square is:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [3, 1, 2],
 [2, 3, 1]]
```

Another is:

```
[[3, 1, 2],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [1, 2, 3]]
```

Given an integer input **n** where **n > 0**, determine how many Latin Squares there are with a size **n  × n**, where the possible values are anything from **1** to **n** inclusive.

### Examples:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 12
4 -> 576
5 -> 161280
6 -> 812851200
7 -> 61479419904000
11 -> 776966836171770144107444346734230682311065600000
```

This is OEIS sequence [A002860](http://oeis.org/A002860). It has a Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

Answers are only required to support inputs up to 6, due to anything above that being greater than 2<sup>32</sup>. However, while this is not strictly enforceable, your *algorithm* must work for all inputs.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79676/rotation-safe-latin-squares).

Comment: Are you sure counting Latin squares is NP complete? Can you please give a reference?

Comment: @xnor Actually, I'm not sure that this problem specifically is NP complete, but I know something else related to Latin Squares is. As I don't have any proof for this problem specifically, I've removed it.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of completing a partially filled Latin square?

Comment: @xnor Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>67</s> <s>56</s> <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
D[Permanent@a^n,##]&@@Join@@(a=x~Array~{n=#,#})&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcy9CsIwEADgVzkIlAoH4u8WuFJx6NQ9RDgkYKC5QLiCUtpXj25O3/Yl1ldIrPHJdfohfZ5Fbb25MZTEEkSJH4LG@IZoyFGIWrbvrSuFP9si1qBZd00dSxR1fZ7mJPdckvtvsCdYDghHhBPCGeGCcF29r18)

Uses Theorem 5.1 in [this article](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v17i1a1): if X is an *n* by *n* matrix whose entries are distinct variables, then the number of *n* by *n* Latin squares is equal to the coefficient of the product of all these variables in per(X)<sup>*n*</sup>, where per(X) is the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) of X. Here, we obtain that coefficient by differentiating with respect to all of the variables, once each (which leaves a constant).

Regarding running time: TIO was happy to deal with inputs 1 through 6, and my laptop can handle 7 in a bit over 6 minutes. I didn't try 8.

Choice quotations included in the article about this formula's practicality:

> The use of MacMahon's result by mere mortals seems doomed. 
>   – Riordan
>
> One should not wish to actually perform, even in a computer algebra package like Maple, MacMahon's counting method.
>   – Van Leijenhorst

## Another Mathematica solution, 52 bytes

```
LineGraph@CompleteGraph@{#,#}~ChromaticPolynomial~#&
```

Much less efficient (only inputs 1 through 4 are viable) but somewhat more readable.

Uses the fact that Latin squares of size *n* are precisely the *n*-colorings of the *n* by *n* [rook's graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook%27s_graph), which is the [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of the [complete bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph) K<sub>*n*,*n*</sub>, and is an excellent example of Mathematica's occasional tendency to look like a natural-language explanation of the algorithm with prepositions replaced by random symbols.

In practice, `GraphData@{"Rook",{#,#}}~ChromaticPolynomial~#&` is only 47 bytes and works for all feasible inputs, but it fails to satisfy the criterion of being a general algorithm (since `GraphData` hardcodes small rook graphs, but does not generate arbitrarily large ones).

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
Œ!ṗµfZ€L
```

Brute force solution. Inputs **5** and higher will time out on TIO.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWHO6cf2poW9ahpjc9/k6BDW4/uOdwO5Lj/BwA)

#### How it works

```
Œ!ṗµfZ€L  Main link. Argument: n

Œ!        Generate all permutations of R := [1, ..., n].
  ṗ       Take the n-th Cartesian power, yielding the array A of all n×n matrices
          whose rows are permutations of R.
   µ      New chain. Argument: A
     Z€   Zip each; transpose each matrix in A, yielding the array B of all n×n
          matrices whose columns are permutations of R.
    f     Filter; keep only matrices that appear in A and B.
       L  Compute the length, counting the kept matrices.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
l@K^.pQQCMK
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%40K%5E.pQQCMK&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3&debug=0)**

### How it works

```
l@K^.pQQCMK   - Full program.

    .pQ       - All permutations of the range [0, input).
   ^   Q      - To the Cartesian power of the input.
  K           - Assign to a variable K.
 @            - The intersection of K.
        CMK   - With the list of all elements in K transposed.
l             - Length.
```

As this is brute force, anything higher than **4** will Memory Error on Herokuapp or time out on TiO.

Comment: You can shave two bytes by avoiding `K`: `l@FCMB^.p`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 91 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=0,s={''},x=0:k<n*n>x and f(n,k+1,s|{x+k/n,~x-k%n})+f(n,k,s,x+n)or len(s)>n*n*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBDoIwFAXXeoq/IVD6jVB2xHKXGmwkxQehLGoAr16r25nMzO/1OUHFaPVoXvfeENjpir3e8vzgoKvW3VCiC2TQky2SljX7fQvSXcGfcHEZDiH/hj0HCTEtND5QeNGlslTRJgAaQDUrbtrzaV4GrL@ZiM0X)

---

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 102 bytes**

```python
lambda n:sum(all(len({(k/r%n,i/n**k%n)for k in range(n*n)})/n/n for r in(1,n))for i in range(n**n**2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpBCsIwEEbhtZ5iNoWZEAhNdwVv4iZioyHp3zLWhYhnj40r4e2@t762@wJf4@lcS5gv10AYH8@ZQylcJvCbs9MONjkYkztIXJQyJZAG3CaGgXzEwYGa6C7cW8jvS/@f2fMitQEa9NbbYTweVk3YKDKkDl8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>138</s> <s>134</s> 124 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
def f(n):r=range(n);print sum(map(set,zip(*m))==n*[set(r)]for m in product(permutations(r),repeat=n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYyxCkIxDAB3vyJjUt4kTkq/RByKL9WCTUKaN@jP127HcZx9461ynrO6dmjBHqqfAa2beqTTzhUqCl09e5EXL7yZNwkYR8deDAfH9muGqRPlLOm@BDo9qjqso4C57scz0Nj7ESWayljB5mxcIgvRrHih@Qc)

Brute forces, very slow. Works for `n=1..4` on tio

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 102 bytes

```
Length@Select[Subsets[Permutations@Range@#,{s=#}],Union[Sort/@Table[#[[i]]&/@#,{i,s}]]=={Range@s}&]s!&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcvLCoMwEIXhfZ8iRcgqIL1sA3mALqS2q2EWUUYNaARnXEmePbUUiruPw38mLwNNXkLrc6esyg@KvQyuppFagXptmIShomVaZc/myO7pY0@uMBvbIqF5x32Fel6kdC/fjAQFQEDU5bcJhhOitdvvxUkjn3WulhBFuQ4uePr7evDt4DvmDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 90 bytes

Brute force!

```ruby
->n{x=[*1..n]
y=*x.permutation
y.product(*[y]*~-n).count{|a|a.transpose.all?{|b|x-b==[]}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcXBCgIhEADQu1/RsQQHtrpaHyJz0G0Xgm0UdwRF7deN2Hd5MbkyVj3Ug2rWRk4AhKJomSEs8ZPY8tuTKBCif6WZz9IUlF9FF5h9Iq7NNgscLe3B7wvYbXvW5lpWTmuDvfcRTquZUPy7Ht2O7jh@)